# The category of finite locally-free commutative group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schemes, group-schemes

I'm trying to understand the properties of the category $\mathcal{FL}/S$ of finite locally-free commutative group schemes over an arbitrary base-scheme $S$. I know it is not in general an abelian category: Over the integers the morphism $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to\mu_2$ given by the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(T^2-1)\to\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with $T\mapsto (1,-1)$ is a monomorphism and an epimorphism in $\mathcal{FL}/\mathbb{Z}$ but it is clearly not an isomorphism.

What I don't know: Does every morphism in $\mathcal{FL}/S$ have a kernel and/or a cokernel?

One has a notion of short exact sequences in $\mathcal{FL}/S$: If $f:G'\to G$ and $g:G\to G''$ are morphisms in $\mathcal{FL}/S$ we say that the sequence $0\to G'\to G\to G''\to 0$ is exact if its image under the embedding of $\mathcal{FL}/S$ into the category of abelian fppf-sheaves is exact. How can we detect in $\mathcal{FL}/S$ whether a sequence is exact? Specifically: If $f$ is a kernel of $g$ and if $g$ is a cokernel of $f$ (both in $\mathcal{FL}/S$), is the corresponding sequence exact?

I'd appreciate (references for) answers to any of these questions.

Comment: What does locally free mean in this context?

Comment: We consider commutative group schemes G over S such that the structural morphism f:G->S is finite locally free, i.e. it is affine and the direct image f_* O_G is a finitely generated locally free O_S module.

Answer (score 12):

Voici tout ce qu'il y a à savoir sur cette catégorie FL/S.

En toutes généralités, c'est une catégorie exacte au sens de Quillen. Plus précisément, le plongement de FL/S dans la catégorie des faisceaux de groupes abéliens fppf sur $S$ font de FL/S une sous-catégorie stable par extensions dans cette catégorie abélienne de faisceaux fppf. Dans une catégorie exacte on dispose d'une notion de monomorphismes et épimorphismes stricts: ce sont ceux qui peuvent s'insérer dans une suite exacte. Alors, si $f:G\rightarrow H$ est un morphisme de schémas en groupes, $f$ est un monomorphisme strict si et seulement si c'est une immersion fermée. De plus, $f$ est un épimorphisme strict si et seulement si c'est un morphisme fidèlement plat.

En général cette catégorie exacte n'est pas abélienne. Comme rappelé précédemment c'est cependant le cas si $S$ est le spectre d'un corps.

Maintenant supposons que $S$ soit le spectre d'un anneau de valuation d'inégales caractéristiques que je note $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Lorsque $e_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p} < p-1$ Raynaud a montré que c'est une catégorie abélienne. De plus, le foncteur fibre générique $G\mapsto G\otimes K$ est pleinement fidèle et identifie FL/S à une sous-catégorie abélienne de FL/$spec(K)$ (i.e., après un choix d'une clôture algébrique $\overline{K}$ de $K$, une sous-catégorie abélienne de la catégorie des $Gal(\overline{K}|K)$-modules discrets finis en tant que groupe abélien).

Lorsque $e \geq p-1$ le résultat précédent est faux. Néanmoins on a le résultat suivant: dans FL/S tout morphisme possède un noyau et un conoyau. Plus précisément, si $f$ est un morphisme dans FL/S alors le platifié de $\ker f$ ($\ker f =$ noyau usuel dans la catégorie des schémas en groupes non-nécessairement plats) (platifié= on tue la $p$-torsion) est un noyau dans $FL/S$ du morphisme $f$. On construit de même l'image de $f$ comme adhérence schématique de l'image en fibre générique. Cependant, la catégorie précédente n'est pas abélienne. Soit en effet $K=\mathbb{Q}_p (\zeta_p)$ et 
$$
f: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \longrightarrow \mu_p
$$
le morphisme qui à $\bar{1}\in \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ associe $\zeta_p\in \mu_p$. Alors, $f$ est un isomorphisme en fibres génériques. On en déduit que dans FL/S les noyaux et conoyaux de $f$ sont nuls. Ce n'est cependant pas un isomorphisme !

Answer (score 10):

Even if kernels (etc.) exist in the category of finite flat commutative group schemes over a scheme, they won't have good properties, and so probably won't be interesting. For example, they won't commute with base change: the kernel of $Z/2Z\to\mu_2$ over Z is zero, but over $F_2$ is is $Z/2Z$.

On the other hand, for a homomorphism whose kernel is flat, everything works as expected: the kernel, cokernel, image, and co-image exist, and the map from the co-image to the image is an isomorphism.

In the category of group schemes of finite type over a field, the isomorphism theorems from group theory hold. In particular, kernels exist, quotients by normal subgroups exist, and the the map from the co-image to the image is an isomorphism (this fails when you don't allow nilpotents in the coordinate rings, which is why you won't find it in any of the standard texts Borel, Humphreys, Springer). From this it follows immediately that the category of commutative group schemes of finite type over a field is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

If the base $S$ is Spec of a Dedekind domain, say $A$, and one restricts to finite flat groups schemes with etale generic fibres (which is no restriction if the fraction field of $A$ has char. 0), then one can form kernels and cokernels in the category of finite flat group schemes by taking scheme-theoretic closures of the corresponding notions on the generic fibre, and this can be useful.  (Of course, one doesnt' get an abelian category: the map
${\mathbb Z}/2 {\mathbb Z} \rightarrow \mu_2$ has trivial kernel and cokernel, but is not an isomorhpism.)

An illustration of how this method can be used is given in e.g. in my joint paper with Calegari [On the
ramification of Hecke algebras at Einstein primes](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/ramification.pdf).

(The point of the restriction to a Dedekind base is that in this case, torsion free, which is what you get with scheme-theoretic closure from the generic fibre, coincides with flat.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there are some kernels and cokernels in $FL/S$. Moreover, the kernels should correspond to those in the category of fppf-sheaves (since you consider only FLAT schemes over S). The situation with cokernels is worse.

For your second question the answer is probably "Yes" (though maybe one needs some restrictions on S). I would suggest you to look at the generic fibre of your exact sequence. There is a paper Raunad M. Schemas en groupes de type $(p,\dots,p)$}
Bull. Soc. Math. France. 1974. v. 102. P. 241--280. Raynaud proves that (under some restrictions) all group subschemes and factor-schemes of the generic fibre of G could be lifted to  subschemes and factor-schemes of G itself in a unique way. You should obtain all G' and G'' coming from all possible short exact sequences (with G in the middle) this way.